# Mail server with Golang

Tags: email, go, postfix-mta

I have a valid mail server, with SSL certificates, DNS and PTR records and an overall secure configuration.

I am able to send mails from the terminal using sendmail tool. But when I try with this code :

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/smtp"
)

func main(){
        err := smtp.SendMail("localhost:25",nil, "yo@testgolang.com", []string {"someemail@gmail.com"}, []byte("This is a test form golang"))
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
}
```

I get the following error :

```
x509: certificate is valid for mydomain.com, not localhost
```

What should I change in my code ( or in the server config ) to be able to send mails from my code.

Comment: What happens if you connect to `mydomain.com` instead of `localhost`? That should probably fix it. You can also change your MTA's setup to not use TLS on localhost connections.

Comment: I had to connect to mydomain.com in Gos codeas you say but i was getting relay access denied. Ao i also added my host network in my networks for the relay to work.i guess that is not veru secure as my host will relay emailfrom another host too. But only like that i was able to make it work

Answer (score 1):

The source of the error is that, for security reasons, the involved parties expect hostnames to match the ones in the certificate. `sendmail` is probably not checking certificates (I haven't found mention `grep`ing the manpage).

The solution is to connect to the server using the proper domain name, or for testing to create a certificate that matches the domain name `localhost`.